# C++ concept that checks a value for requirements

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a way to use c++20s concepts to check that a value meets some requirements?

Lets say I am writing some sort of container that uses paging and i want to make the page size a template parameter.

```
template<typename Type, std::size_t PageSize>
class container;
```

I could use a static assert with a constexpr function to check if `PageSize` is a power of two inside the class body.

But is there a way to use the new concepts to restrain `PageSize`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++20 introduced [`std::has_single_bit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit) to check if `x` is an integral power of two, so you can use `requires` expression to constrain `PageSize`.

```
#include <bit>

template<typename Type, std::size_t PageSize>
  requires (std::has_single_bit(PageSize))
class container { };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aGvr69q7b)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to constrain the template parameters of the class.

```
constexpr bool is_power_of_two(std::size_t x) { /*... */ }

template<typename Type, std::size_t PageSize>
    requires ( is_power_of_two(PageSize) )
class container;
```